# Fastest way of creating a dictionary which acts as a group-by style look-up in a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping, vectorization

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array whose values correspond to a label or class. For example, if
`A = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]`, then positions `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 3)` correspond to the class '0' and `(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), etc` correspond to class '1'. This is a very simple example but, in general, I would be dealing with matrices with much more items.

What I want to do is essentially build a dictionary where a key corresponds to each class and its corresponding value is a list of tuples, where each tuple corresponds to a position of the input matrix whose value is the key. In other words, group the input matrix by its values and obtain a list of positions where each unique value occurs.

For now, I have the following code:

```
S = {i: [] for i in range(A.max() + 1)}
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    index = np.arange(A[i].shape[0])
    sort_idx = np.argsort(A[i])
    cnt = np.bincount(A[i])
    result = np.split(index[sort_idx], np.cumsum(cnt[:-1]))
    for j, k in enumerate(result):
        S[j] += [(i, z) for z in k]
```

Where A is my input matrix.
That takes around 0.4 ms to run on average on a 500x500 matrix. Nonetheless, I feel like it can be improved further, by making a better use of vectorization (maybe).

Could someone guide me on how it could be made simpler and/or faster? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with this dict exactly?  This sounds like a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: It's part of a segmentation problem, so I'm more interested in knowing which (X,Y) belong to which class.

Comment: There may be tools more suited to what you're doing, if you want to expand on that

Comment: Yes, I believe scikit has some built-in libraries, like "labels", which more or less allows something like this. But instead of looking up a way of implementing it in my code, I figured I'd just do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this much more simply using `np.argwhere` and `np.unique`:

```
S = {}
for key in np.unique(A):
    S[key] = np.argwhere(A==key)
```

Note that this returns a 2D numpy array.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. It's much better to get a numpy array right away as the value of the key.